# search and replace the value inside tags using script

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have a file like this. `abc.txt`

```
<ra><r>12.34</r><e>235</e><a>34.908</a><r>23</r><a>234.09</a><p>234</p><a>23</a></ra>
<hello>sadfaf</hello>
<hi>hiisadf</hi>
<ra><s>asdf</s><qw>345</qw><a>345</a><po>234</po><a>345</a></ra>
```

What I have to do is I have to find `<ra>` tag  and for inside `<ra>` tag there is `<a>` tag whose valeus I have to replace by 0.00.

```
grep "<ra>" "abc.txt" | grep "<a>"
```

I am able to find  and  but I dont know how to change.

Output file for this:-

```
<ra><r>12.34</r><e>235</e><a>0.00</a><r>23</r><a>0.00</a><p>234</p><a>0.00</a></ra>
<hello>sadfaf</hello>
<hi>hiisadf</hi>
<ra><s>asdf</s><qw>345</qw><a>0.00</a><po>234</po><a>0.00</a></ra>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sed should work:

```
sed -i.bak '/<ra>/s~\(<a>\)[^<]*\(</a>\)~\10.00\2~g' abc.txt
<ra><r>12.34</r><e>235</e><a>0.00</a><r>23</r><a>0.00</a><p>234</p><a>0.00</a></ra>
<hello>sadfaf</hello>
<hi>hiisadf</hi>
<ra><s>asdf</s><qw>345</qw><a>0.00</a><po>234</po><a>0.00</a></ra>
```

Because of `-i` (inline) switch this sed will save the changes in original file itself.

Comment: `/<ra>/` finds all lines that have `<ra>` in them and then substitute `s~\(<a>\)[^<]*\(</a>\)~\10.00\2~g` command is executed in found lines. Substitute command finds text from `<a>` to `</a>` and replaces it with `<a>0.00</a>` (using matched groups #1 and #2).

Answer (score 3):

Replace using `awk` and `gsub`

```
awk '/^<ra>/ {gsub(/<a>[^<]*</,"<a>0.00<")}1' file
<ra><r>12.34</r><e>235</e><a>0.00</a><r>23</r><a>0.00</a><p>234</p><a>0.00</a></ra>
<hello>sadfaf</hello>
<hi>hiisadf</hi>
<ra><s>asdf</s><qw>345</qw><a>0.00</a><po>234</po><a>0.00</a></ra>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the following code:

```
$ sed -e '/<ra>/ s#<a>[^<]*<#<a>0.00<#g' file
<ra><r>12.34</r><e>235</e><a>0.00</a><r>23</r><a>0.00</a><p>234</p><a>0.00</a></ra>
<hello>sadfaf</hello>
<hi>hiisadf</hi>
<ra><s>asdf</s><qw>345</qw><a>0.00</a><po>234</po><a>0.00</a></ra>
```

It is based on this structure:

```
Print # in lines starting with BBB just if there was not ^# before
sed -e '/^BBB/ s/^#*/#/' -i file
```

changing the delimiter to a `#` so we do not need to escape the `/` in `</a>`.

Note that if you want the file to be updated you need to add `-i` to the sed (`sed -i -e ...`). Otherwise the result will be printed in the stdout.

Comment: You don not need the final `/a>`, start of `<` is enough, like: `sed -e '/<ra>/ s#<a>[^<]*<#<a>0.00<#g'`

Comment: That's a good point, @Jotne. However, I added `</a>` so that cases like `<a>hello<b>how are you</b></a>` could be accepted, That is, to allow other tags to be inside the `<a>` / `</a>`. Anyway, I see it is not doing it properly, so I will use the expression you suggest. Thanks!

Comment: You point is good as well, did forget that there can be other tags like bold.